# getting OAUthException on FacebookMobile.login

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

i'm trying to login to facebook in order to share a link through facebook sharer

> http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=

i'm init the FacebookMobile on application start with no access token and than tries the below:

```
var facebookWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
                        facebookWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle (0,0, stage.width, stage.height-100);
                        var permissions:Array = ["publish_stream"];
                        FacebookMobile.login(onfacebookLogin, this.stage, permissions, facebookWebView);
```

the login fails and show an execption on the flash builder 4.5 emulator:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "Error validating application.",
>         "type": "OAuthException"
>      }
>   }

anyone encountered it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your application missing some configuration.
Check the facebook app page properties.

Comment: where can i access it? what kind of type of configuration?